# Lock user interaction to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, locking, wkwebview, user-interaction

I want to lock user interaction to WKWebView so when user interact with WKWebView, gestures are not passed to views behind (table view, page view controller etc).

I have found this done on google maps. When user interact with GMSMapView, all gestures in background are disabled.

Any solutions?

Comment: Add A view as overlay on all your Subviews and Add WebView as Child view to that overlayview

Comment: That won't work if webView is inside table view cell...

Comment: can you share your View Hierarchy ?

Comment: UITabViewController - UINavigationController - UIPageViewController - UIViewController - UITableView - UITableViewCell - WKWebView :D

Comment: So if I have something embedded in table cell, interacting left/right will change vc in pager, while top/bottom will scroll table view...

Comment: Did you try : http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5917-uiwebview-inside-a-scrollview.html

Comment: Sry no solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have found right solution. I have added pan gesture to webView that does nothing. This will lock user interaction to webView and won't be passed to responders below.